# Facing problem in setting margins in bootsrap cards

Tags: html, css

I am working on a mobile website **( 360x640)** .

**Firstly,** I am not able to fill the empty spaces on the right with text **in the talk to astrologer section** . I am not able to shift 25 years of text on the right side.

**Secondly,** I am not able to align font awesome with the text .
Can someone help me in setting margins so that it looks exactly similar to what I want ??

**Thirdly** , Phone font awesome which I want  `<i class="fas fa-phone-alt"></i>` is not working ,

**What do I want to achieve ??**

[image]

**My Frontend**

[image]

Please help in achieving what I want to !!!!

```css
body {
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.footer {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(241, 241, 241);
  color: orangered;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.experience {
  float: right;
}

.orange {
  background-color: #f78336;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: white;
}

i {
  color: #f78336;
}

.call-btn {
  background-color: #f78336;
  padding: 15px;
  margin-left: 40px;
  width: 300px;
  box-shadow: 5px 10px #c8c8c8;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-F3w7mX95PdgyTmZZMECAngseQB83DfGTowi0iMjiWaeVhAn4FJkqJByhZMI3AhiU" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../assets/talk.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-B4dIYHKNBt8Bc12p+WXckhzcICo0wtJAoU8YZTY5qE0Id1GSseTk6S+L3BlXeVIU" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <title>Talk to an Astrologer</title>
</head>

<body>


<!-- Search bar-->
<div class ="search-bar sticky-top " >
<ul class="navbar navbar-light bg-light justify-content-end ">
    <a class="navbar-brand " href="# ">
      <img src="../assets/search.png " width="30 " height="30 " alt=" ">
    </a>
    <a class="navbar-brand " href="# ">
        <img src="../assets/filter.png " width="30 " height="30 " alt=" ">
      </a>
      <a class="navbar-brand " href="# ">
        <img src="../assets/sort.png " width="30 " height="30 " alt=" ">
      </a>
</ul>

</div>


<!--- MAIN SECTION   -->
<div class="main mb-3 ">
<h1><b>Talk to an Astrologer</b></h1>

<div class="card flex-row flex-wrap mb-3 mx-3 ">
    <div class="card-header border-0 ">
        <img src="//placehold.it/200 " width="200 " height ="200 " alt=" ">
    </div>
    <div class="card-block mx-2 ">
        <span style ="float: right; "class ="experience ">25 years</span> 
        <h2 class="card-title "><b>Arvind Shukla</b></h2>
      
        <p class="card-text "><i class="fas fa-user "></i>Cofee Cup Reading ,<br>Falit Jyotish,Kundali Grah Dosh,<br>Vastu,Astrology,Vedic Astrology,<br>Palmistry,Numerology,Face<br> Reading,Tarot</p>
        <p class="card-text "><i class="fas fa-om "></i>English,Hindi</p>
        <p class="card-text "><i class="fas fa-money-bill-wave "></i><b>₹100/Min</b></p>
        <a href="# " class="btn orange call-btn ; "> <i class="fas fa-phone " style = color:white></i>Talk on Call</a>
       
    </div>
</div>


</div>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this one it will work as expected ,

```
 <body>


<!-- Search bar-->

<!--- MAIN SECTION   -->
<div class="main mb-3 ">
    <h1><b>Talk to an Astrologer</b></h1>

    <div class="card ">
        <div class="card-header border-0 ">
            <img src="//placehold.it/200 " width="200 " height ="200 " alt=" ">
        </div>
        <div class="card-block mx-2 ">
            <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: row; place-content: space-between; width: 100%">
                <h2 class="card-title "><b>Arvind Shukla</b></h2>
                <span style ="float: right; " class ="experience ">25 years</span>
            </div>
            <p class="card-text "><i class="fas fa-user "></i>Cofee Cup Reading ,<br>Falit Jyotish,Kundali Grah Dosh,<br>Vastu,Astrology,Vedic Astrology,<br>Palmistry,Numerology,Face<br> Reading,Tarot</p>
            <p class="card-text "><i class="fas fa-om "></i>English,Hindi</p>
            <p class="card-text "><i class="fas fa-money-bill-wave "></i><b>₹100/Min</b></p>
            <div class="btn orange call-btn">
                <i class="fas fa-phone " style = color:white></i>
                <a href="#"> </a>
                Talk on Call
            </div>


        </div>
    </div>


</div>
</div>
</body>
```

css ,

```
body {
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    font-size: 20px!important;
}

.footer {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgb(241, 241, 241);
    color: orangered;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px !important;
}

.experience {
    float: right;
}

.orange {
    background-color: #f78336;
    font-size: 20px !important;
    color: white;
}

i {
    color: #f78336;
}

.call-btn {
    background-color: #f78336;
    padding: 15px;
    margin-left: 40px;
    width: 300px;
    box-shadow: 5px 10px #c8c8c8;
}

.card{
    border: 1px solid #707070;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-flow: row;
    place-content: stretch;
    justify-content: start;
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
.card-block{
    width: 100%;
}
.card-header{
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
}
```

for font check wheather you add the font awesome script of install locally the font awasome in you project

Comment: Thank you so much, Charlie  !!!!!!!!!!! also, I want to add this phone icon in the button but this alt phone icon is not working , can you please help me in add  <i class=" fas fa-phone-alt"></i> in place of the previous one .

Comment: The phone icon class name is wrong. Try this one ```<i class="fa fa-phone " style = color:white></i> ```

Comment: i think in your code every thing is good in font awasome icon, cheak the icon color . your button background and  icon color  are same  so it's not visible to you , try with some other @NatashaAnderson  '<i class="fas fa-phone"></i>' this is left face call icon,'<i class="fas fa-phone-alt"></i>'  this is right faceing call icons , try with what you need

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following code. It is not perfect but its OK i guess.

```
body {
  margin: 0px;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.footer {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(241, 241, 241);
  color: orangered;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
}


.orange {
  background-color: #f78336;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: white;
}

i {
  color: #f78336;
}

.call-btn {
  background-color: #f78336;
  padding: 15px;
  margin-left: 40px;
  width: 300px;
  box-shadow: 5px 10px #c8c8c8;
}

.card{
  max-width: 750px;
  width: auto;
}

.fas,.fa{
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-F3w7mX95PdgyTmZZMECAngseQB83DfGTowi0iMjiWaeVhAn4FJkqJByhZMI3AhiU" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./style.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-B4dIYHKNBt8Bc12p+WXckhzcICo0wtJAoU8YZTY5qE0Id1GSseTk6S+L3BlXeVIU" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <title>Talk to an Astrologer</title>
</head>

<body>


<!-- Search bar-->

<ul class="navbar navbar-light bg-light justify-content-between">
  
  <h1><b>Talk to an Astrologer</b></h1>
  <div>
    <a class="navbar-brand " href="# ">
      <img src="../assets/search.png " width="30 " height="30 " alt=" ">
    </a>
    <a class="navbar-brand " href="# ">
        <img src="../assets/filter.png " width="30 " height="30 " alt=" ">
      </a>
      <a class="navbar-brand " href="# ">
        <img src="../assets/sort.png " width="30 " height="30 " alt=" ">
      </a>
  </div>

   
</ul>




<!--- MAIN SECTION   -->
<div class="main mb-3 ">

<div class="card flex-row flex-wrap mb-3 justify-content-between" >
  
    <div class="card-header border-0 w-1/4">
        <img src="//placehold.it/200 "alt=" ">
    </div>
    <div class="card-block flex justify-content-between w-3/4 mx-auto">
        <span style ="float: right; "class ="experience text-center">25 years</span> 
        <h2 class="card-title "><b>Arvind Shukla</b></h2>
      
        <p class="card-text "><i class="fas fa-user "></i>Cofee Cup Reading ,<br>Falit Jyotish,Kundali Grah Dosh,<br>Vastu,Astrology,Vedic Astrology,<br>Palmistry,Numerology,Face<br> Reading,Tarot</p>
        <p class="card-text "><i class="fas fa-om "></i>English,Hindi</p>
        <p class="card-text "><i class="fas fa-money-bill-wave"></i><b>₹100/Min</b></p>
        <a href="# " class="btn orange call-btn ; "> <i class="fa fa-phone " style = color:white></i>Talk on Call</a>
       
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```